# Why do I find two menu bars when I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: upgrade, updates, vlc

I'm not sure if this is a problem with VLC or the OS itself, I don't find this issue with any other apps I've tried so far though.
Here is a screenshot of it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug (possibly in Unity) that affects other users as well. for more info see : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1542519